# Does a Django site with a Tastypie interface need two codebases?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a Django project with several apps. My project is now getting to the point it needs an API. I'm planning to have the API on a different server using tastypie. However, the API will use the same models as the website.

So far I see my only option is as follows...

Copy the apps to the server which means I have two apps using the same models and now have to maintain two code bases --- bad!

So, how do other handle this? What options do I have?

Can my models be shared somehow?

Comment: You could put the models into a separate project and have the two apps use it as a library or using something like git submodules. Alternately, keep the code for the web parts of both projects together, and only handle what gets run in configuration, but this sounds a little ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend splitting your project like this.

Every time you edit a model you have to edit it on both immediately or risk things getting out of sync. This will get very very painful, instead;

**Is the server the bottleneck?** Split site and api machines (but using the same `models.py`) and share the connection to the DB somewhere.

**Is the DB the bottleneck?** Scale up the DB to a faster machine / cluster and use the same site for  to supply web and api.

Either way, One codebase, One set of models, One DB!

Comment: how would one 'Split site and api machines'? as an example?

Answer (score 3):

1. For this to be meaningful, you likely need to connect to the same database
2. Why would you need two codebases? You have two copies of a single codebase.

Comment: Yes I connect to the same database and have the same models etc. One server will be my website the other an API.

Comment: I don't want really the same app but use of the same models within the apps on both servers, i.e. my website and the API

Comment: Within a project you can have many apps, within a server you can have many projects with many apps, databases and settings. Any python file can be appended to any process's python path within the server, so again what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is I want to share the same model with my website (one server) and a API (on different server) without having to have two models that are the same.

Comment: @User7 Again, why does that require two codebases for the models?

Answer (score 1):

Have your app with models in a separate repo and go with [`git-submodule`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: git-submodule seems interesting

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you run the api on the same server on a different port? that will save you a lot of problems to start with. Sharing database connections cross servers will likely require you to think about security, a lot.

Also if you are reusing the same apps in different projects you might want to package and version your apps for comfort. Think about the real problem you are trying to solve and always keep that in mind. There are plenty of solutions for every problem, finding the right one makes a difference.

Comment: I want to split across two servers website and API, they don't have the same apps but need the same models if you get what I mean.

Comment: maybe I should say I want to reuse my models from the app with the  api as its the same database and model etc